# If $A$ is an initial segment of an ordinal $\alpha$, then either $A\in\alpha$ or $A=\alpha$.

Tags: set-theory

Definition: $A\subseteq \alpha$ is an initial segment if for each $a\in A$ and $b\in \alpha$, $b<a$ implies $b\in A$.

$b<a$ denotes $b\in a$ when both $b$ and $a$ are ordinals.

So the hint was to first show that $A$ is an ordinal, which I did. But now I need to use this result to prove that either $A\in\alpha$ or $A=\alpha$.

So suppose $A\neq\alpha$. We want to show that $A\in\alpha$.
Since $A\neq\alpha$, the set $\alpha\setminus A$ is nonempty. Since $\alpha$ is an ordinal, it is well ordered. So let $\beta\in\alpha\setminus A$ be the least element. Also since $A$ is an initial segment, for each $x\in A$, we must have $x\in\beta$.

The problem is that how do I know $\beta$ is an ordinal? And can I thus conclude $A\in\beta$, and hence $A\in\alpha$ by transitivity?

Comment: In this setting you'll have $A = \beta$, so try showing that.

Comment: But where have I used the fact that $A$ is an ordinal?

Comment: What is your definition of an ordinal? Does it include that all its elements are ordinals as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "So the hint was to first show that $A$ is an ordinal, which I did."

Then you are almost ready.

Ordinals are comparable when it comes to relation $\in$ so if $\alpha$ and $A$ are ordinals then: $$\alpha\in A\vee \alpha=A\vee A\in\alpha$$

It remains to rule out that $\alpha\in A$.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Notice that if we suppose that $A\subseteq \alpha$ and $A$ is an initial segment of $\alpha$ but $A\neq \alpha$, as you said, there is a minimal element $\beta\in\alpha\setminus A$. The idea will be now to show that $\beta=A$, thus concluding that $A=\beta\in A$.

To show that $\beta=A$, we do it by double inclusion. First, notice that if $x\in \beta$ then $x\in \alpha$ and $x<\beta$, so we have $x\in A$ by the minimality of $\beta$. Conversely, suppose $x\in A$. Then $x\in \alpha$ (as $A\subseteq \alpha$) and we have two options:

- $x\geq \beta$: In this case, either $x=\beta$ or we can use the fact that $A$ is an initial segment of $\alpha$ to obtain $\beta\in A$, which is absurd by the choice of $\beta$.
- $x<\beta$: In this case, as the order inside the ordinal $\alpha$ is given by $\in$, we conclude that $x\in\beta$.